# Typescript new compiler status

Tags: typescript

I experience huge improvements in compile time while using new compiler at [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript). But, I couldn't see the status of readiness of using it. Is it ok to use it during development and may use the stable/released one for production. Is there a place I can check the status of milestones before a stable release?

thanks.

Comment: `But, I couldn't see the status of readiness of using it. Is it ok to use it during development and may use the stable/released one for production. ` That is what we've been doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the milestones on GitHub, seems there isn't a lot open for 1.1 but I don't know how complete the milestones are.
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/milestones/TypeScript%201.1

I think it is pretty safe to use the new one for development, tried it myself too and never had any issues with it (that I'm aware of).

I'm not sure what the next version will be because the 1.2 milestone has lots of integration bugs with Visual Studio assigned to it. So not sure what the 1.1 release will be like.